# How to use, not installed into system, custom fonts in PyCharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, fonts, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I know that PyCharm is using fonts installed in the system.
My problem is like this:
I have corporate workspace. I can't install my own fonts. IT won't install  them. I need to use an accessibility font.

Is there a way to force PyCharm to use custom font other than installing it?

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I use windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the `.ttf` files into `PYCHARM_INSTALL_DIR\jre64\jre\lib\fonts` and restart it.

Make sure to install all the font face files (plain, bold, italic, bold-italic), otherwise you will get incorrect font rendering in the IDE.